# Drawing outside the bounds of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, cliptobounds

I am trying to add a "post-it note"-like image to all the cells in my `UITableView`. This image needs to draw (partly) outside of the bounds of the `UITableViewCell`.

When setting `clipToBounds` to `NO`, the image is indeed drawn outside the cell's bounds. However, (quite logically) the image is drawn below the `UITableView` separator lines and section headers.

I guess I could try adding the images directly to the `UITableView`, on top of all other elements. However, it might become rather complex trying to figure out the exact location of each cell in the `UITableView`, as I am using section headers.

So, before embarking on that journey, I was wondering if there might be an easier solution.

Comment: I don't think you will find a solution for this. 

If you want to draw above the separator, you can just hide the separator, and draw a line to simulate it. 

But the issue here is that the cells have a certain hierarchy that they are added as subviews. Cell above another cell, will just hide the view that you drew outside the cell using clips to bound.

Answer (score 3):

You could try hiding the separator and then drawing your own separator behind the post-it in the UITableViewCell. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an affine transform to move the post-it image to its intended location, and change the edge insets of the separator view so it isn't drawn over the image.

```
postItImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 20)
separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 30, bottom: 0, right: 50)
```

It depends what your UI needs to look like. This would obviously change the separator insets for *all* cells, which may or may not be acceptable ;-)